# Android TelephonyManager.listen registers multiple instances of listener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I have written a simple broadcast receiver to block calls from specific numbers. The problem I faced was that TelephonyManager.listen method registered multiple listeners. I understand that I should create only one instance of PhoneStateListener inside onReceive(). Thats What I did. But still it didn't solve the issue. Below is my code.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.context = context;

    if(dbHelper == null)
    {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    if(telMan == null)
    {
        telMan = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    }
    if(listener == null)
    {
        listener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    }
    telMan.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    rejectedNumbers = dbHelper.getNumbers();

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String phoneNumber)
    {
        if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
        {   
            //rest of my code
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I may have done something wrong but I can't find it. Can someone help me find what have I done wrong.

P.S. I solved the issue by unregistering the listener at the end of onReceive method. Is it the correct way?

Comment: first question- does using broadcastreceiver in service give any added adavantage? because in case of phone state change my receiver's on receive method will get called anyway. second question - is using service or not related to my problem?

Comment: first of all you do not understand android's basics (application components)... in short: everything outside onRecive in BroadcastRevicer is bad(makes no sense) ... that's why you should start service (wakefull one) and setup listener there .... and stop self(service) + unregister the PhoneStateListener after `//rest of my code`

Comment: from documentation( **did you read it at least once?** ): *Receiver Lifecycle

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.*

Answer (score 0):

If You unregistered the Receiver at the end of your overridden method, is you again registering it on second call ?